# IngestFromStreamAsync method does not work

Tags: azure-data-explorer, data-ingestion

I manage to ingest data successfully using below code

```cs
var kcsbDM = new KustoConnectionStringBuilder(
    "https://test123.southeastasia.kusto.windows.net", 
    "testdb")
  .WithAadApplicationTokenAuthentication(acquireTokenTask.AccessToken);

using (var ingestClient = KustoIngestFactory.CreateDirectIngestClient(kcsbDM))            
{

    var ingestProps = new KustoQueuedIngestionProperties("testdb", "TraceLog");
    ingestProps.ReportLevel = IngestionReportLevel.FailuresOnly;
    ingestProps.ReportMethod = IngestionReportMethod.Queue;
    ingestProps.Format = DataSourceFormat.json;
 
    //generate datastream and columnmapping

    ingestProps.IngestionMapping = new IngestionMapping() { 
      IngestionMappings = columnMappings };
    var ingestionResult = ingestClient.IngestFromStream(memStream, ingestProps);
}
```

when I try to use QueuedClient and IngestFromStreamAsync, the code is executed successfully but no any data is ingested into database even after 30 minutes

```cs
var kcsbDM = new KustoConnectionStringBuilder(
    "https://ingest-test123.southeastasia.kusto.windows.net", 
    "testdb")
  .WithAadApplicationTokenAuthentication(acquireTokenTask.AccessToken);

using (var ingestClient = KustoIngestFactory.CreateQueuedIngestClient(kcsbDM))          
{

    var ingestProps = new KustoQueuedIngestionProperties("testdb", "TraceLog");
    ingestProps.ReportLevel = IngestionReportLevel.FailuresOnly;
    ingestProps.ReportMethod = IngestionReportMethod.Queue;
    ingestProps.Format = DataSourceFormat.json;
 
    //generate datastream and columnmapping

    ingestProps.IngestionMapping = new IngestionMapping() { 
      IngestionMappings = columnMappings };
    var ingestionResult = ingestClient.IngestFromStreamAsync(memStream, ingestProps);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the reason finally, need to enable stream ingestion in the table:

```
.alter table TraceLog policy streamingingestion enable
```

See [the Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-streaming) for details.

Comment: I tried to enable the streamingingestion on the table, but still have the same issue. Program runs fine but no data actually ingested. Did you also set up a wait timer?

Comment: It also wasn't enough for me

Answer (score 1):

Try running .show ingestion failures on "https://test123.southeastasia.kusto.windows.net" endpoint, see if there are ingestion error.
Also, you set Queue reporting method, you can get the detailed result by reading from the queue.

```
ingestProps.ReportLevel = IngestionReportLevel.FailuresOnly;
ingestProps.ReportMethod = IngestionReportMethod.Queue;
```

(On the first example you used `KustoQueuedIngestionProperties`, you should use `KustoIngestionProperties`. `KustoQueuedIngestionProperties` has additional properties that will be ignored by the ingest client, ReportLevel and ReportMethod for example)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please change the line to:

```cs
var ingestionResult = await ingestClient.IngestFromStreamAsync(memStream, ingestProps);
```

Also please note that queued ingestion has a batching stage of up to 5 minutes before the data is actually ingested:
[IngestionBatching policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/batchingpolicy)
[.show table ingestion batching policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/batching-policy)

Comment: I mean, await your async operation, just to make sure you are not going out of scope before the async operation completes.

Comment: Thanks for reminder, I add System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)) , but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

enable streamingestion policy is actually only needed if

- stream ingestion is turned on in the cluster (azure portal)
- the code is using `CreateManagedStreamingIngestClient`

the ManagedStreamingIngestClient will first try stream ingesting the data, if it fails a few times, then it will use the QueuedClient

if the ingesting data is smaller, under 4MB, it's recommended to use this client.

if using QueuedClient, you can try

```
.show commands-and-queries | | where StartedOn > ago(20m) and Text contains "{YourTableName}" and CommandType =="DataIngestPull"
```

This can give you the command executed; however it could have latency > 5 mins

Finally, you can check the status with any client you use, do this

```
            StreamDescription description = new StreamDescription
            {
                SourceId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Stream = dataStream
            };
```

then you have the source id

ingesting by calling this:

```
var checker = await client.IngestFromStreamAsync(description, ingestProps);
```

after that, call

```
var statusCheck = checker.GetIngestionStatusBySourceId(description.sourceId.Value);
```

You can figure out the status of this ingestion job. It's better wrapped in a separate thread, so you can keep checking once a few seconds, for example.